# How to run a maven project on mac

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, pom.xml

I am trying to run a simple maven project from the mac terminal.
Here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <!-- here we specify that we want to use the main method within the Controller class -->
                    <mainClass>com.helloworld.Countries</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

I did maven package.
and when I try to run:

```bash
java -jar target/HelloWorld-1.0.jar
```

… I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONValue
```

Is the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` only on macOS? I did the same project on Windows and it works fine.

Is there anyway that we can make this independent of OS?

Comment: A JAR file does not contain dependencies which means if you like to have a jar file which contains the dependencies you have to create a so called executable jar. This can be achieved by using maven-assembly-plugin or via maven-shade-plugin.... This is unrelated to Mac/Linux/Windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use Maven-shade-plugin. Here is my final POM.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>  
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->  
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>3.1.0</version>  
            <configuration>  
                <archive>  
                    <manifest>  
                        <mainClass>com.test.HelloWorld</mainClass>  
                    </manifest>  
                </archive>  
            </configuration>  
        </plugin>  
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```